# Angular 4 - universal hide HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side, universal, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to do server side rendering with angular and hide the HTTP requests for the user, aka do the http requests on the server side ?

I have created an api but I do not want to expose it to the outside world, I do not want that you can see the response data in the network tab.

So is it possible with angular to do this or do i need to use a different framework to achieve this ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a single-page application at all; have you considered a more traditional server-side app?

Comment: I know, i really like angular haha but i thought maybe maybe there was a solution

Comment: To expose the API to multiple resources to consume is the meaning of API. It is just the matter of how you are authenticated to use the API. So I think you can use the traditional server-side rendering to match with your purpose :D